# How i can read a yaml dict and use it inside helm-template

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am creating a helm libary that i will use in other helm chart and i want to have a common values file in this libary. I have thought to do it using a external file and load it like below but i haven't be able to do it. What i am doing wrong? Thanks

```
##defaultRoutesHelm.yaml
route:
  dev:
    path: dev.es
    labels:
     router: alpha
  staging:
    path: staging.es
    labels:
     router: beta
--
{{- $helmRoute := .Files.Get "config/defaultRoutesHelm.yaml" | fromYaml }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-configmap
data:
  path: {{get $helmRoute 'route.dev.path'}}
```

Comment: Which part goes wrong?  Do you get an error?  Would it make more sense to include this setup in your chart's `values.yaml` file, where it would be visible in `.Values`?